# Group by in treeview format

Tags: c#, sql, aggregate-functions

I have a DB where i keep data of people who make loans. Loans can be made by just one person or by a group of people. I show you part of my database schema.

[image]

'Acreditados' keeps the relationship between 'Personas'(person) and 'Creditos'(loans) so one person could have multiple loans and one loan could have been made by multiple persons.
'Agrupaciones' keeps the relationship between 'acreditados' (a person who already has a loan) and 'grupos' (loans by group have a group name). 
Finally 'movimientos' keeps fees and payments for everyone.

The question here is how do I query my database to group all payments (movimientos) by loan (creditos) and, if it is an individual loan show name of the person but if it is a groupal loan show name of the group?

I already have the following query:

```
SELECT CR.id_credito, SUM(M.monto) AS Monto, SUM(M.interes) AS Interes, SUM(M.iva) AS IVA, SUM(M.capital) AS Capital, M.fecha_mov
FROM movimientos AS M
JOIN cargos AS C ON C.id_movimiento = M.id_movimiento
JOIN acreditados AS A ON A.id_acreditado = M.id_acreditado
JOIN creditos AS CR ON CR.id_credito = A.id_credito
WHERE C.status = 0 
GROUP BY CR.id_credito, M.fecha_mov
ORDER BY M.fecha_mov
```

With this query I group payments by 'creditos'(loan) and by date since every payment has a different date. But how do I Join this with 'personas'(person) table in order to get the name of the person who made the loan and if it is a loan by group show name of the group? In fact I don't if this is possible with a conventional query and the porpouse of this is to make a threeview in c# where the name of the group would be the parent and every person a child node. Individual loans would be parent nodes without childs.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Make a 'personal' loan a group with only one member (default to member's name?), saves masses of issues, and gives you the facility to add and remove other loaners to the 'group'. Trust me you don't want this group / single split, it will get in your face more times than this one.

Comment: So you think inserting individual loans in 'agrupaciones' with group name set to default member's name would solve this split? But what about the threeview porpouse? If I do this how can I make a threeview displaying person information in child nodes?

Comment: Your problem is coming from dealing with loans for one or for many as two different things. Loan -> Group -> Borrowers. You can skip the intermediate node if only one borrower in group, but that's Child count when building the tree, your query will be the same and be presentation agnostic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be very leary about joining additional tables that could possibly duplicate rows and thereby throw off all your aggregate functions. What I mean is this:

Assume you have 2 people attached to the loan, so you start with the loan payment, join back to the loan, and then join to the people that belong to that loan. You will now have 2 records for every loan payment (one for each person) that you now have to deal with.

What I would recommend doing is to use an OUTER APPLY to join the fields back to what you need. If you've never used an outer/cross apply, just think of it as a subquery in a select statement:

```
SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 i.someColumn FROM innerTable i WHERE i.ID = t.ID) FROM someTable AS t
```

Except that it's within the join itself. What this means is that you can use an IN SCOPE subquery in the FROM clause to join back. In fact, this is probably your best bet, in order to keep all payments localized to just loans and keep all persons/groups in this other query. So your query would look something like this:

```
SELECT CR.id_credito, SUM(M.monto) AS Monto, SUM(M.interes) AS Interes, SUM(M.iva) AS IVA, SUM(M.capital) AS Capital, M.fecha_mov, ISNULL(tg.nombre, tp.nombre) Nombre
FROM movimientos AS M
JOIN cargos AS C ON C.id_movimiento = M.id_movimiento
JOIN acreditados AS A ON A.id_acreditado = M.id_acreditado
JOIN creditos AS CR ON CR.id_credito = A.id_credito
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 G.nombre FROM grupos G JOIN agrupaciones AG on AG.id_grupo = G.id_grupo WHERE AG.id_acreditado = A.id_acreditado) tg
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 P.nombre FROM personas P WHERE P.id_persona = A.id_persona) tp
WHERE C.status = 0 
GROUP BY CR.id_credito, M.fecha_mov, ISNULL(tg.nombre, tp.nombre)
ORDER BY M.fecha_mov
```

One thing to take away from this is that the OUTER APPLY doesn't need to be joined back to the rest of the tables in the FROM clause, because it's already working under the assumption that you're querying based on values from the rest of the FROM clause sources (tables). Also, don't forget to alias your APPLY queries (in this case, it's `tg` and `tp`).

*Edit: Just noticed the requirement to be in a treeview format. I'll tackle that now.*

It seems that no matter what, you want ALL the records for each person to be returned as well. In this situation, you want the same record to be returned for all people within a group. The best way I see to do that is to join back to the persons table as a regular join (instead of an apply), and then just group by `tg.nombre` and `personas.nombre` fields as well. That way you still get every person that's attached to the loan, but you also get the group name returned so that if there is a group you can use that as a root node in the tree.

As for actually creating this as a treeview, you're gonna have to do some extra work in order to actually get it setup that way. What I would suggest is to get the query in a usable format, and compile it together using LINQ grouping.

The query would then need to be changed this way:
Change the line `OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 P.nombre FROM personas P WHERE P.id_persona = A.id_persona) tp` in the above change to `INNER JOIN personas P on P.id_persona = A.id_persona`, change the select/grouping from `ISNULL(tg.nombre, tp.nombre) Nombre` to `tg.nombre Grupo, P.nombre Nombre`. In your code, after getting back your query results, use the following LINQ statement to get your query (assuming it's at least .NET 3.5):

```
// Assume the query results are in dtLoanPayments strongly typed datatable.
// Also assume we have a TreeView called tvLoans
dtLoanPayments.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(tr => tr.Grupo).ToList().ForEach(tr =>
{
    (tr.Key == null ? tvLoans.Nodes : tvLoans.Nodes.Add(tr.Key)).AddRange
        (tr.Select(ti => { TreeNode tempNode = new TreeNode(ti.Nombre); tempNode.Tag = ti; return tempNode; }).ToArray());
});
```

Again, it really just depends on how you want them displayed. If you want further grouping by the person, then you would need to do another GroupBy before the inner `tr.Select` so it would be `tr.GroupBy(ti => ti.Personas).Select` and you'd have to create another TreeNode for every loan payment record. In these types of situations, just remember that it's usually a lot easier to keep the display and data logic separate. On the query side, just make sure the data you're getting back is correct, and then deal with formatting in your application code.

*Edit: To answer your comment question, adding some more code.*
It's all just a matter of transforming your list of items into properly nested TreeNode objects. I think my explanation above kinda answers it, but I can give you the code with explanations of exactly what is going on. Assuming your list is called `amortList` and your TreeView is called `tvLoans`, then try this:

```
// First, group by group name. If it's null (meaning no group), then it will just be 
// the person's name. Doing ToList() after grouping so we can do a ForEach.
amortList.GroupBy(tr => string.IsNullOrEmpty(tr.Grupo) ? tvLoans : tvLoans.Add(tr.Grupo)).ToList()
    .ForEach(tr => 
    // This gives us the node we'll be adding each record to as the key. Now all
    // we need to do is add all loan records to the node, grouping by person
    {
        tr.Key.Nodes.AddRange(
            // Group by person's name first
            tr.GroupBy(ti => new TreeNode(ti.Nombre))
                // Then transform into each node (loan payment, etc) and add to the person node.
                .Select(ti => 
                { 
                    ti.Key.Nodes.AddRange(
                        ti.Select(tn => new TreeNode(/*Use whatever field here to display.*/).ToArray());
                    return ti.Key; // Return TreeNode.
                }).ToArray());
    }
```

If this is still confusing, you can do a foreach that accomplishes the same thing (and is easier to understand).

```
foreach(_Amortizacion amNode in amortList)
{
    // Using Null Coalescing to create the node if it doesn't exist.
    // First check if group is null. If it isn't, try to pull the node and create it if it doesn't exist.
    TreeNodeCollection workingNode = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(amNode.Grupo) ?
        (tvLoans.Nodes[amNode.Grupo] ?? tvLoans.Nodes.Add(amNode.Grupo)).Nodes :
        tvLoans.Nodes;
    // At this point, workingNode is the NodeCollection we'll be adding the person to. Creating if doesn't exist.
    workingNode = (workingNode[amNode.Personas] ?? workingNode.Add(amNode.Personas)).Nodes;
    // Now we're adding the actual loan record to the person Node.
    workingNode.Add(new TreeNode(/* This is what will show up in TreeView. */) { Tag = amNode, Name = /* Specify a key here, in case you want to search. */ });
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for all your help. I've already made my query using LINQ and got results in the same way you suggested. My results are stored in a List<_Amortizacion> where _Amortizacion has the fields needed. How do I use LINQ to make the treeview part using that list?

Comment: Added on to my answer again, giving you a few more options to work with. This was all done in this window, so there's likely going to be some syntax errors (nothing you shouldn't be able to discern).

Comment: Perfect, great explanation. Thanks for taking some of your time on this.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question as it relates to your current schema, you could use:

- LEFT JOIN acreditados to personas and agrupaciones
- JOIN agrupaciones to grupos
- Use CASE Statement determine if nombre is pulled from personas or grupos

As for building this in a treeview, you would want to create a recursive query to pull the data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: but what would be the boolean expression evaluated in CASE statement? I tried something like SELECT 'Nombre'= 
 CASE 
  WHEN P.id_persona THEN P.nombres
  WHEN G.id_grupo THEN G.nombre
 END
,CR.id_credito ... but didn't work